# Delete a partiular line and 17 lines after that

Tags: shell-script

I have a report that pulls some information IP address and host name, etc. 
Some some servers have a heading like:
NOTICE TO USERS
(followed by about 17 lines of text information)
when I cat the file, I do not need the NOTICE (and 17 more line after that on some servers).  How can I get rid of it?

Comment: "about 17 lines"...?

Comment: We expect the question's requirements to be more precise. Show some sample text and explain which lines you want to exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below sed command to achieve the same

```
sed '/NOTICE TO USERS/,+17d' filename
```

IF you want to delete the 17lines with NOTICE TO USERS line in same file means you can use -i option in sed command

```
sed -i '/NOTICE TO USERS/,+17d' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/NOTICE TO USERS/ { lastdelline=NR+17 };
    lastdelline>0 && NR<=lastdelline { next; }; { print; }' inputfile
```

Comment: Why `NR+5` and not `NR+17`?

Comment: @codeforester 5 is "about" 17 :-)

Comment: I tried the awk commnad, it did not take out any thing.   The NOTICE TO USERS (followed by 17 lines) is a part of /etc/issue.  My script does ssh from on server to a number of servers and gathers information like IP, host name ,etc.    I am still trying to get rid off NOTICE TO USERS (followed by 17 lines) which appears on some servers.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: awk '/NOTICE TO USERS/ { lastdelline=NR+17 }; lastdelline>0 && NR<=lastdelline { next; }; { print; }' test.info